# Django Moderation System

Tags: python, django

So I am creating a Django application where users can register and also create posts. I want to be able to moderate this and have it so when a user creates a post it has to be approved by an Admin before it can go live. I tried using https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation but it just wasn't working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: What issue do you encounter.?  Just follow the setup process mentioned in the official documentation

Comment: "It just wasn't working for me" doesn't tell us much. What *EXACTLY* was the problem you faced?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I'm remembering would be to have a boolean attribute in the `Post` model that will only be `True` if it was approved by a `Moderator`.

After that you just need to show the posts that have that value set to `True`.

Comment: Ah yes this sounds pretty good. Will give it a try when I am working on it next!

Comment: So what if a user modify the post.? even if it goes through your trivial approval process the others fields of the post are altered and will be available to the public ...

Comment: Editing a Post can be set to change the Post status to unapproved which will make it requiring Admin approval again.
Again this is a simple approach to it, I'm sure there's better ways